# сохранить значение select в сессии пользователя

Tags: javascript, html, python, css, flask

нигде не смог найти ничего более путного чем слова "ну здесь надо сессии использовать" , "попробуй через куки". Каким бы то ни было способом, но мне нужно сохранить значение выбранного select-a, чтобы потом пользователь смог просто нажать кнопку "добавить в избранное" не выбирая по второму кругу категорию. Сейчас , как видно на фотке это работает так : выбираешь категорию, ищешь, выбираешь еще раз дурацкую категорию (внизу) и наконец-то нажимаешь кнопку "добавить в избранное". А все потому, что при перезагрузке страницы что бы ты ни выбрал - слетает на первую option "Блюда" [Ссылка на Гит](https://github.com/artisakov/vigilant-journey/tree/master)

```
<form method='post' action='/search'>
  <select id='selector' name='select' class="calc-form-input">
    <option>Блюда</option>
    <option>Продукты</option>
    <option>Конкретные продукты</option>
    <option>Конкретные блюда</option>
  </select>
<input id='query' type='text' name='input_query'  autocomplete="on" spellcheck lang='ru' placeholder=" Поиск ">
<button class='btn' id='btn_query'>Искать</button>
</form>
```

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
def search():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['select'] == 'Блюда': 
            search_string = request.form['input_query']
            con = sqlite3.connect('C:/FFlaskApplication/diacompanion.db')
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT (name) name ,_id FROM"
                        " receipts WHERE category LIKE ? GROUP BY name", ('%{}%'.format(search_string),))
            result = cur.fetchall()
            con.close()
            print('Были выбраны блюда')
        elif request.form['select'] == 'Продукты': 
            search_string = request.form['input_query']
            con = sqlite3.connect('C:/FFlaskApplication/diacompanion.db')
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT (name) name ,_id FROM"
                        " constant_food WHERE category LIKE ? GROUP BY name", ('%{}%'.format(search_string),))
            result = cur.fetchall() 
            con.close()
        elif  request.form['select'] == 'Конкретные продукты': 
            search_string = request.form['input_query']
            con = sqlite3.connect('C:/FFlaskApplication/diacompanion.db')
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT (name) name,_id FROM constant_food WHERE name LIKE ? GROUP BY name", ('%{}%'.format(search_string),))
            result = cur.fetchall() 
            con.close()
        else:
            search_string = request.form['input_query']
            con = sqlite3.connect('C:/FFlaskApplication/diacompanion.db')
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT (name) name,_id FROM receipts WHERE name LIKE ? GROUP BY name", ('%{}%'.format(search_string),))
            result = cur.fetchall() 
            con.close()                                     

    return render_template('index.html', result=result, name=current_user.username)
```

[image: первый скрин]

Comment: Попробуйте использовать SQLAlchemy и Flask-wtf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        session['select'] = request.form['select']
```